# Error: No space left on device

Tags: tag

Desktop properties: free space 56.5 mb, same for all other folders. Running off a USB, looking to solve memory capacity issue.

Ubuntu 20.04.3 LT

Comment: If you are running from USB, do you have writeable partition? What does `mount`say? Open a terminal, execute the command and paste the answer into your question (not in a comment). Use [this link](https://askubuntu.com/posts/1389816/edit) to edit

Answer (score 1):

56MB of free space is critically low.  If the system needs to perform a write that exceeds the available space, it won't be able to.  Depending on what kinds of operations fail, it could cause a system crash or it could corrupt your software.

Corruption due to failed writes can cause a "snowball effect" and can quickly get to a point where the only practical solution is to reinstall the OS.

**You should free up space immediately.** Either you need to delete some things, or you need to expand the partition where Ubuntu is installed.

FYI: the **minimum** system requirement for Ubuntu Desktop is 25GB. It would be wise to allocate more space, especially if you plan on keeping files and documents under your file system and if you plan to install any additional software.